# What does JALR with only 1 argument and offset do?

Tags: assembly, disassembly, riscv

So I am looking at some riscv assembly code and basically trying to figure out what's wrong.
However, I stumbled upon the following code:

```
 80001a2:   00000097            auipc   ra,0x0
 80001a6:   62e080e7            jalr    1582(ra) # 80007d0 <memset>
```

I think I understand the auipc, namely adding the pc to my return address, however I don't understand the jalr here.
When I look it up, it says the usage is:
**jalr xD, xL (offset)**
I am guessing in my code the (ra) is the offset, but what is 1582 here? The source? the destination? both?

Comment: _The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume I: User-Level ISA_ has a table of pseudo-instructions, in which it says that `jalr rs` expands to `jalr x1, rs, 0` (with `x1` just being a different name for `ra`). So by extension, `jalr rs, imm` ought to expand into `jalr x1, rs, imm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the disassembler assumes the normal default destination register (`ra`) to write the return address into, so leaves that implicit.

So `1582(ra)` would be how it shows the target address calculations, like an addressing mode for a load or store, `offset(reg)`.  RISC-V `jalr` supports some immediate offset bits, making it possible to call any target address with a 2-instruction sequence of `auipc` to get 20 bits of relative offset, and `jalr` supplying the other 12.  That's pretty clearly what's going on here. [Understanding the auipc+jalr sequence used for function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43956612/understanding-the-auipcjalr-sequence-used-for-function-calls)

If you want to double-check, disassemble it yourself.

(The `0x0` offset in the `auipc` instruction might be due to `memset` having ended up nearby.  These look like "real" addresses so it's not an unlinked `.o`.  I'm guessing this is a statically-linked executable?  The fact that `memset` would be so close wasn't known until link time; too late to optimize to a `jal` relative branch I guess.)