# RISCV - How to call a function given its address?

Tags: assembly, function-pointers, riscv

I have a register `a2` that stores an address of another function. How do I call that function?

After I preserved the values of a0 and a1, I tried `jal ra, a2` and `jal ra, 0(a2)`. Both did not work. I think it is because `jal` is expecting a label name instead of a register. But I do not know any other way to call a function.

Comment: You want `jalr a2`.

Comment: Related: [Understanding the auipc+jalr sequence used for function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43956612) shows one way compilers use it